# Find lines between a pattern and end of file?

Tags: perl

I need to find the lines containing the word **find** between the word **START** and the end of file.

I've tried this, but doesn't work unless I specify an END pattern:

```
perl -ne 'if ((/START/ .. /.*\s*/) && /find/) {print "$_"} else {print "\n"}' file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following

```
perl -lne '$p=1 if /START/; print if $p && /find/' file
```

**EDIT** *(as per OP's comment)*

> I print the line if I find a match otherwise I print an empty line.

```
perl -lne '$p=1 if /START/; if ($p && /find/) {print $_} else {print ""}' file
```

Comment: It worked for the initial form, but i edited and added else {print "\n"}.

Comment: @georgiana_e sorry, didn't understand your updated requirement. Can you please explain a bit? may be it would be better to update that in question.

Comment: I print the line if I find a match otherwise I print an empty line. I need to do that because I will apply diff with another file and I want to preserve the line numbers.

Comment: @georgiana_e Please check EDIT in solution.

Comment: print ""; in Perl doesn't print anything - Perl's print doesn't output a line end. You can use say ""; in more modern Perls or print "\n"; in older Perls.

Answer (score 1):

The end expression of your range operator is a regular expression with everything optional `/.*\s*/` so it will match *every line*, and the range will always terminate on the same line it started.

You can use the end of file test to make the range extend to the last line. At the same time you may as well tidy things up with the conditional operator instead of `if` / `else`.

This will do what you ask.

```
perl -ne 'print((/START/ .. eof) && /find/ ? $_ : "\n")' myfile
```

Comment: +1. compact and pure perl way. mine was derived from awk practice.